# Can value of text input field be inaccessible from script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension containing content script which basically installs listeners for "onchange" event for all text inputs on the page to capture their values when needed.
My question is next: can there be some input field that actually hides its real value not only masking it to the user, but making it inaccessible to any script as well? Is that possible at all in JavaScript?

For example:

```
<body>
   ...
  <input type="password" id="inpPwd">
   ...
</body>
```

Content script:

```
  function onchange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  var inp = document.getElementById("inpPwd");
  inp.addEventListener("change", onchange);
```

So that, once user enters something into field "inpPwd", that entered value cannot be obtained in onchange function.

Comment: where do you have this javascript code?

Comment: It is a part of Chrome extension, in particular, a content script (*.js) that is injected into web page by Chrome.

Comment: I dont think so, js has read and write access to the entire DOM. You cannot have any element that is inaccessible in js.

Comment: Also, if you make a textbox inaccessible to js [assuming you could], wouldn't it make it inaccessible to any scripts on the page itself?

Comment: This is what I am thinking too, but, for example, the script which is part of web page (not my extension), installs onkeypress or oninput event listeners, grabs just entered value and stores it into some global variable, and then puts something different into value of the control. Like:           var val = ""; function oninput(event) { val = event.target.value; event.target.value = "bla-bla-bla"}. In this case, will my onchange event listener receive the value correctly and not "bla-bla-bla"?

Comment: If a field is not readble by human and script then what is it for?

Comment: @YuriySharamaha that code is buggy. When I type "a" into the textbox its value is replaced with "blablabla" and when i type "b" for my intended input "ab", the textbox will contain "blablablab". I will quickly press Ctrl+W and continue with my work :p

Comment: The code below does what I am telling about:
`<body onload="body_load()">
<input id="inp" type="text" onchange="myFunction(event)">
<p id="demo"/>
<script>
var val = "";
function onchange(event) {
    var x = event.target.value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The value is: " + x + " Global value is: " + val; 
}
function body_load() {
    document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", onchange);
}
function myFunction(event) {
    val  = event.target.value;
    event.target.value = "***";
}
</script>
</body>`

Comment: In onchange function I am not getting the value that user has typed into the control, because original event handler masked it. In this case how can I obtain the real value of that control?

Comment: Use edit on your post to add details, code in comments is unreadable.